# computation using template literal in jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Why doesn't this work?

```
<div style={{height: `${(2/1) %}` }}>
</div>
```

I expect to have 50% for height. Can I do that in jsx? But as I know anything within the `{}` is a javascript expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic rule:

> Only js expressions need to be put inside `{}`.

---

Issue is, placement of `%` is wrong, write it like this:

```
style={{ height: `${(2/1)}%` }}
```

It should be out of `${}`, otherwise it will be treated as **[Remainder (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)** and expect another value after %. When you define it outside of `${}` it will work as a percentage.

Example:

```
style= {`${value}%`}
```

**Update:**

To define style with react we need to pass an object, keys will be css properties and values will be their value, so in your case you need to put blue inside `''`.

Use this:

```
style={{height: `${1/2}%`, background: 'blue' }}
```

Comment: this won't work? <div className="bar" style={{height: `${1/2} %`, 'background: blue' }}>

Comment: the height still not working, here's my attempt. https://jsfiddle.net/tkqsdr64/ you can inspect element, style is not added at all.

Comment: just curios why space even matter here.

Comment: because it will become `height: '50 %'`, and it should be `height: '50%'`  or `'50px'` no space between number and unit :)